# Show only upper directory usage inside docker running in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, overlay

My project will run clients' (docker) containers with kubernetes. And the command `df -h` inside docker container will show the host `/` usage like this:

```
root@aggregator-demo-vgpovusabzqf-578f547cc5-rc8g6:/# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                            1.8T  227G  1.5T  14% /
tmpfs                               64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  1.8T  227G  1.5T  14% /etc/hosts
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              504G   12K  504G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                              252G     0  252G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                              252G     0  252G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                              252G     0  252G   0% /sys/firmware
```

which is not quite helpful for user to understand how much storage already used. And I see some container platforms which can show only the actually user usage like this:

```
root@container-bc574b56:~# df -lh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          25G  574M   25G   3% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           378G     0  378G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              40G     0   40G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb        150M  4.0K  150M   1% /init
tmpfs           378G   12K  378G   1% /proc/driver/nvidia
/dev/sda2       219G   26G  184G  13% /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
udev            378G     0  378G   0% /dev/nvidiactl
tmpfs           378G     0  378G   0% /proc/asound
tmpfs           378G     0  378G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           378G     0  378G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           378G     0  378G   0% /sys/firmware
```

The `/` directory shows `Avail` is `25Gi` which is the actual container limitation and the `Used` is `574M` which is the docker upper directory usage. How to implement like this? Maybe this is not the capability of docker and it may use some other implementation?

Comment: I'd normally expect a container to be running a single process, and fairly autonomously (especially in Kubernetes, where the cluster can occasionally destroy them without much warning).  What is your use case where an operator has used `kubectl exec` to get a debugging shell, and what would they be able to do about the process's ephemeral-storage utilization?  Is this a programming question or more about system administration?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have to say this is not what you expect (single process, easily destory and stateless), this is a usecase like vm and the end users can even save and restore the updated containers to a new image. So it is necessary to limit the usage of `/` to prevent user use up the whole disk.

Comment: In fact, Kubernetes is not typically a use case like a VM setup.  It sounds like you might be looking for actual virtual machines running full operating systems with dedicated system administrators, and not lightweight disposable single-process containers in a cluster environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df` simply queries the filesystem for available space.

If you're using the standard `overlay2` driver, the container filesystem is just a view onto the host filesystem; there's no way for `df` to provide a container specific value because there is no separate filesystem.

If you're using something like the `devicemapper`, `zfs`, or `btrfs` [storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/), then each container has its own unique filesystem, so `df` can provide information that is specific to the container.

Comment: That is very helpful for me, thanks very much. But I my second code block it shows `overlay          25G  574M   25G   3% /` does this mean that it is using an overlay fs ?

Comment: It does mean the container root filesystem is managed via overlayfs, but it doesn't tell us anything about how the container environment is setting things up. If you can give us specific details about the container orchestrator you're using, the container runtime in use, and how storage is configured, we can probably provide a better answer.